# how to select an element with an additional class in css

Tags: html, css

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a 
{
     color: black;
     font-weight: normal;
}
```

This applies a black color to all my bootstrap navbar items.
Now to certain `a href` links I add a class called `current` depending on which link I last clicked.

How do I add this class to above css rule to set a specific link for that color?

On adding a rule for

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{}
```

this rule doesnt show up in chrome developer tools for that element..weird

Comment: `.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.current {}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.current {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: black;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.current {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Edit and explain what you did here!

Answer (score 0):

In Css  parent > child like as we have to mention so you have to specify   `a.current` or `.current`

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.current 
{
     color: black;
     font-weight: normal;
}
```

or

```
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li >.current 
    {
         color: black;
         font-weight: normal;
    }
```